# Quotient Remainder Theorem and prime numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is there any integer n ≥ −90 such that n+100, n+200, n+400, n+1200 are all prime numbers? If yes, give an example. If not, prove it.

Comment: Hint:  try it $\pmod 3$

Answer (score 1):

Hint

$$(n+100)(n+200)(n+1200)\equiv n(n+1)(n+2)\pmod3$$

So, exactly one of them must be divisible by $3$